# How to reuse angular observable across multiple components? (To avoid having to duplicate a request twice?)

Tags: javascript, angular, observable

I have a service "MyHttpService" that includes an observable like this:

```
grabData() {
return this.http.get('myaddress')
                         .map((res:Response) => {return res.json()})
                         .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')); 
}
```

I have 2 components. OneComponent and TwoComponent that both have "MyHttpService" injected that depend on the data returned by MyHttpService.

OneComponent loads up first. TwoComponent loads up after button click.

Within the onNgInit() of each component I have:

```
     this.myHttpService.grabData()
        .subscribe(
              data => {
 // do something to the data
});
```

Is it correct to assume that even though I have this subscribe in both components, that there are not going to be multiple HTTP requests called and that the call to "grabData()" when TwoComponent loads is the same data already pulled by OneComponent? Or will it make a new call? I want to avoid multiple HTTP requests to the same endpoint. If multiple calls are being made each time a component that has this is called, what is the best way to handle this so that I don't have multiple calls to the service each time I initialize TwoComponent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Http` service returns what are known as *cold observables*. This means that every new subscriber will cause the work for that observable to be done again, which in the case of `Http`, is to make the network request.

Luckily, there are mechanisms in RxJS to allow you to *publish* (a.k.a multicast or multiplex) an observable so that multiple subscribers do not cause multiple requests.

The way I usually do this for `Http` is with the `.publishReplay(1).refCount()` pair of operators. The `.publishReplay(1)` means that later subscribers get the most recent successful value straight away, without making another request. `.refCount()` means that the first subscriber makes the request, and the last one to unsubscribe cleans up the original `Http` observable.

Version [5.4.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#540-2017-05-09) added a shortcut for these two operators, which is `.shareReplay(1)`.

Just whack either version on the end of the line in your `grabData()` service method, and it should work like you desire.

```
grabData() {
    return this.http.get('myaddress')
                    .map((res:Response) => {return res.json()})
                    .catch((error:any) => 
                         Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
                    .publishReplay(1).refCount(); // or .shareReplay(1)
}
```

Comment: _and the last one to unsubscribe cleans up the original Http observable._ - right, so if some other subscription is made `http` request is executed again, correct? so basically the http request result will be shared until there's at least subscriber, then the request would be repeated. `AsyncSubject` seems to be the better alternative here, what do you think?

Comment: @Maximux, could you share what you mean by AsyncSubject method? Based on what I am seeing when using the above method, it looks like when I click the button, the client is making a 2nd request using the same service "grabData()" instead of using the 'cached' value from the shared/first request.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [share](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/share.md) operator to make an observable multicast. This is also relevant within a single component as multiple async bindings to the same osbervable will cause multiple requests to be made. There is a good ng-conf talk [here](https://youtu.be/aZRJOVPMW4k?t=740) that covers the issue.

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/share';

grabData() {
  return this.http.get('myaddress')
                  .map((res:Response) => {return res.json()})
                  .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
                  .share(); 
}
```

Comment: I have a problem with share and dynamic modules, when I navigate between dynamic modules in some calls I lost the subscription with the share operator

Answer (score 3):

When you subscribe in TwoComponent it will cause the http request to be sent again. The best way for you to prevent multiple http calls would be to store the response data in your service and before the http call, check if you have already saved the data and if so just directly returning the data.

Comment: I don't wish to downvote, but this is much less idiomatic use of RxJS, and does not handle the case when the second subscription is made before the network request has returned. The advice I try to stick to is to minimise or eliminate manually subscribing to observables in your services, and ideally your components as well. Instead, compose observables using operators and consume them in the view using the `async` pipe.

Comment: @GregL I need to dive into RxJS more, but I upvoted your answer. I understand your concerns doing it the way I suggested and if there is a way available directly through RxJS than that would definitely be the better choice.

Comment: I have found several issues with `share` and `shareReplay` all related with dynamic modules, I think this could be a feasible solution