# Angular - How to subscribe data one time, in one request, and use it in child components?

Tags: angular, typescript, service, observable

There is a major component of the site I'm developing that I'm trying to turn reusable. It's something like:

```
-> parent
    parent.component.html
    parent.component.scss
    parent.component.ts
   -> child_1
       child_1.component.html
       child_1.component.scss
       child_1.component.ts
   -> child_2
       child_2.component.html
       child_2.component.scss
       child_2.component.ts
(...)
-> services
  -> parent-services
      parent.service.ts
```

The parent.service.ts have the http method, but I need the return of an http request both in child_1.component.ts and child_2.component.ts in order to subscribe data from this request to a reusable variable.

How grab data in **one request on service** then **subscribe once** to populate my html page, which will be used in child_1.component.ts and child_2.component.ts in different ways?

*Obs.: during subscribe I do some data manipulation, like verify if it's null then add some default value, and just copy-paste this block code doesn't appear to be a good solution.

Comment: This solution didn't help me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201555/how-to-reuse-angular-observable-across-multiple-components-to-avoid-having-to

Comment: You could just subscribe and send the http response to child_1 and child_2 from the parent component when it is ready.

Comment: Nice! After some time I understand how to work with data between related and unrelated components (not always EventEmitter is applicable). Great tutorial can be found here: https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a BehaviorSubject as an observable in your service. This BehaviorSubject will contain the value of your common variable that you want to use in both of the components.

Your api call will be in the constructor of your service and this BehaviorSubject will be assigned a value in your service whenever this api call will get response.

Keep this Subject's observable subscribed in your components, as it will have value at some point of time and you can get that value in your components easily.

Consider this code below for reference :-

parent.service.ts :-

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class ParentService {
children = new BehaviorSubject([]);
sharedChildren = this.children.asObservable();
apiUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';

constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
    this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/users`).subscribe((users: any) => {
          console.log('Children fetched on application boot up :-\n', users);
          this.children.next(users);
        })
    }
}
```

child_1.component.ts :-

```
import { ParentService } from 'yourParentServiceClassPath';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class Child_1Component implements OnInit{
    we_siblings;
    constructor(private parentService: ParentService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.parentService.sharedChildren.subscribe((children: any) => {
            this.we_siblings = children;
            console.log('We siblings are', this.we_siblings);
        })
    }
}
```

Similarly, you can create a we_siblings variable in child2_component.ts or any other component and follow the same thing we followed in child1_component.ts

As you have instantiated ParentService in Child_1Component's constructor, so it's constructor will be called when the application will be loading for the first time. Hence, calling the api, bringing data from api and passing it to sharedChildren observable which is being subscribed in your components.

Comment: Thanks! Helped me a lot :D

Comment: Happy to help! @DavidsonLima

Answer (score 1):

You can create a service and use **BehaviorSubject** as shown below and in child you can fetch data via asObservable():

**Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserService {
    private userDataSource: BehaviorSubject<Array<any>> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
    userData = this.userDataSource.asObservable();

    updateUserData(data) {
      this.userDataSource.next(data);
    }
}
```

**In Parent Component:**

```
constructor(
    private myHttpService: MyService,
    private userService: UserService,
  ) { }

arrayData: any[] = [];
flag = false;

fetchData() {
 this.myHttpService.fetchApiData().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.arrayData = data;
        flag = true;
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    )
  if (flag){
    this.userService.updateUserData(this.arrayData);
  }
}
```

**In Child Component:**

```
dataArray: any[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.userData.subscribe(data => this.dataArray = data);
  }
```

And now you can use the values of the *dataArray* in you child component's ts and html.